# Loader is stuck

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So I am building a SPA using react and fetching some images from an API. I want to show a loader till i get a response. I have the code here but the loader does not seem to spin for some reason. I'm not sure why. I am using axios to fetch the API. I have the code for the components below.

photogallery.js

```
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/img-redundant-alt */
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./PhotoGallery.css";
import ImageModal from "./ImageModal";
import Loader from "./Loader";
import axios from "axios";

const PhotoGallery = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const [photos, setPhotos] = useState([]);
  const [selectedPhoto, setSelectedPhoto] = useState(null);

  const headers = {
    Authorization: "my_key",
  };

  const fetchApi = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    await axios
      .get("https://api.pexels.com/v1/curated", { headers })
      .then(({ data }) => {
        const photoUrls = data.photos.map((photo) => photo.src.original);
        setPhotos(photoUrls);
      });
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchApi();
  }, []);

  const handlePhotoClick = (photo) => {
    setSelectedPhoto(photo);
  };

  const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setSelectedPhoto(null);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <div className="photo-gallery">
          {photos.map((photo, index) => (
            <div
              className="photo"
              key={index}
              onClick={() => handlePhotoClick(photo)}
            >
              <img src={photo} alt={`Photo ${index + 1}`} />
            </div>
          ))}
          {selectedPhoto && (
            <ImageModal photo={selectedPhoto} onClose={handleCloseModal} />
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default PhotoGallery;
```

Loader.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./Loader.css";

const Loader = () => {
  return <div className="loader"></div>;
};

export default Loader;
```

Loader.css

```
.loader {
    border: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-left-color: #09f;
    animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
    
  }
  
  @keyframes spin {
    0% {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.